# I am getting error while using Group By clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have written the following query for `group by` clause

```
SELECT  OrderDetails.Quantity,
        OrderDetails.options 
FROM    OrderDetails  
Group by OrderDetails.Quantity,
        OrderDetails.options 
Order by OrderDetails.options DESC
```

`OrderDetails.options` this column is of datatype `nvarchar(255)` and `quantity` is `float`.

But I am getting error like this:

> The text, ntext, and image data types cannot be compared or sorted, except when using IS NULL or LIKE operator.

I am new to SQL can any one please help me out

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the rest of the query?

Comment: I suspect that `OrderDetails.options` is not `NVARCHAR(255)`, and is in fact `TEXT` or `NTEXT`. Can you post your table definition.

Comment: [*`ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead.*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group by should have an aggregate operator so u might need to sum up the order quantity to get it done. Try this out :

```
  SELECT  sum(OrderDetails.Quantity),OrderDetails.options 
  FROM    OrderDetails  
  Group by  OrderDetails.options 
  Order by OrderDetails.options DESC
```

Comment: He is using both columns in group by clause. In that case he don't need aggregate function. The GROUP BY statement is used in conjunction with the aggregate functions to group the result-set by one or more columns. Error he is getting is related to data type.

Answer (score 4):

Double check to make sure that the columns does not have the datatype TEXT or NText. If there is a column that has the datatype Text or NText then you can convert them to use NVARCHAR(MAX).